# UITextView - Scrolling to selected place

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a Notes view controller with a large UITextView in it. When the keyboard is active, I've made sure the contentInset is adjusted so that the user can see what's being typed. This works well.

However, if the textView already has a large amount of text in it and the keyboard isn't active yet, when the user taps on text in the lower portion of the textView, the textView doesn't automatically scroll up to show their cursor. As soon as they start typing, the textView scrolls to the appropriate position, but I'd like the textView to scroll to the position of the cursor as soon as they tap in the textView.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWasShown), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeHidden), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: Notification) {
    let mainViewY = self.view.frame.origin.y
    let textViewY = self.textView.frame.origin.y
    let oneLineHeight = self.textView.font.lineHeight
    let delta = (textViewY - mainViewY) - oneLineHeight
    let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = (keyboardSize?.height)!
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight + delta, 0)
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = textView.contentInset
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

I searched for people asking this question but couldn't find anyone experiencing my particular issue.

How can I ensure that when the user taps the textView to begin typing in a portion of the textView that would be covered by the keyboard, the textView scrolls to show their cursor even before they actually type?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by calling `scrollRangeToVisible` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview/1618613-scrollrangetovisible)) using the text view's `selectedRange`. That method scrolls the text view to any range of text, and the `selectedRange` should be at the position of the cursor.

Comment: This looked promising.. I tried adding `self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(textView.selectedRange)` to my keyboardWasShown method (I tried both before and after changing the insets) and I also tried adding it to the `textViewDidBeginEditing` delegate method. It sometimes scrolls, but most of the time it doesn't... and it seems to let me type without the textView scrolling based on the contentInset (i.e. I can type things where the keyboard is covering the textView--the problem I was solving by adjusting the contentInset). Any tips on how I should utilize that method?

Comment: I had to save `selectedRange` before Keyboard disappears as the selectedRange is reset once the user edits the `attributedText`

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, but I tried out your sample code.

In viewDidLoad, I commented out the second observer (self.keyboardWillBeHidden).

When I ran the simulator and selected any part of a large block of text, the textView did automatically scroll to the correct position.